# ¿Por qué no puedo consultar por esta fecha?

Tags: oracle, sql

Tengo un problema con mi query de oracle.
Este es el query

```
SELECT vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA as "TARJETA",
       vta.DA_FECHA_PROCESO as "FECHA_PROCESO", 
       SUM(vta.VA_CANTIDAD) "CANTIDAD", 
       pro.DE_PRODUCTO as "PRODUCTO",
       vta.CO_CODE_TURNO_HORARIO as "TURNO",
       vta.CLPB_PRODUCTO as "COD_PRODUCTO",
       count(vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA) as "CANT_TRANSACCIONES"
FROM CLPM_VENTA vta
INNER JOIN CLPB_PRODUCTO pro ON vta.CLPB_PRODUCTO = pro.ID
WHERE vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA IS NOT NULL
      --AND vta.DE_MENSAJE IS NOT NULL
      AND vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA <> 0 
      AND vta.DA_FECHA_PROCESO = TO_DATE('21/02/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      --AND vta.DA_FECHA_PROCESO between TO_DATE('21/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30/06/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      AND vta.CLPB_PRODUCTO = 1
GROUP BY vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA, 
         vta.DA_FECHA_PROCESO, 
         vta.CO_CODE_TURNO_HORARIO,
         vta.CLPB_PRODUCTO,
         pro.DE_PRODUCTO
HAVING SUM(vta.VA_CANTIDAD) > 25 AND count(vta.CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA) > 5
```

El temas es que cuando consulto por la fecha siguiente que sería el '22/02/2018' no me arroja error pero si lo consulto por '21/02/2018' me arroja este error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Esto me pasa con  tres fecha '21/02/2018','21/08/2017','25/12/2017'
La verdad que no entiendo por que pasa eso, si el formato de fecha es el correcto debería.

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo uses cadenas del siguiente formato ANSI  para tu fecha 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Prueba a pasar así tus fechas.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema no es la fecha en sí sino los datos, seguramente alguna de las columnas que consideras es numérica no lo es y está fallando la conversión implícita. Revisaría `CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA` mes suena que no es numérico

Comment: Coincido con @PatricioMoracho. No creo que sea la conversión de la fecha en sí, ya que si probamos de forma aislada `SELECT TO_DATE('21/02/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') test FROM ...`  la consulta no arroja ese error. Revisa el tipo de datos de las columnas, sobre todo aquellas en las que empleas criterios con números o funciones de agregación como `SUM`.

Comment: Sería útil disponer de la definición de la tabla

Comment: Nos dejas ver la definicion de las 2 tablas, seria util ver las definicion de las columnas

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho tienes razón el tema era por la conversión implícita en el campo de CO_CODIGO_TARJETA_PERSONA ya que había algunos valores que tenían letras.